# Hiding softkeyboard reliably

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have a application, and need to close the softkeyboard on *a rather large amount of actions*. For example, when **clicking a button**, when a new **layout is drawn**, on **screen orientation change**, when the **controller tells** the UI to, et cetera.
I use the optionsMenuButton to flip view with a ViewFlipper, and obviously I want the keyboard to hide in the flipped view (there is no input field there).

I've tried these so far and tell why these aren't reliable:

This one didn't work because I have lots of editTexts, and other views. I need a more generic one, one that does not require a view as argument, if possible.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This one does not work at all for me:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This one works, but immediately pops the keyboard up again when the view is flipped.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

This one works sometimes, but getCurrentFocus() returns null most of the time.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)            
Context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),      
InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

This one works only if the keyboard is shown:

```
getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
```

This one does not work with the EditText like the first piece of code, but with the root Layout, which changes on orientation change and everytime the oncreate is called. I have different layout XML for landscape/portrait and normal/large. All the root Layouts have the ID `root`. This works nicely the first time, but after that, it doesn't work anymore.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.root).getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Bottomline: I've tried hella lot of softkeyboard hiding methods, but none of them seems to work reliably. **Is there *any* method for hiding the soft keyboard reliably?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you need an `EditText` to bring up the keyboard, find the particular one and use the first method you displayed to hide the keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

However, you will need that `EditText`. First, get all views:

```
public static ArrayList<View> getAllViewsFromRoots(View...roots) {
    ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();
    for (View root : roots) {
        getAllViews(result, root);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void getAllViews(ArrayList<View> allviews, View parent) {
    allviews.add(parent);
    if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)parent;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            getAllViews(allviews, viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, get an `EditText` which is visible.

```
public static EditText getEditText(View root) {
    ArrayList<View> views = getAllViewsFromRoots(root);
    for (View view : views) {
        if (view instanceof EditText && view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            return (EditText) view;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Call somewhere:

```
Toolkit.getEditText(((ViewParent) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0));
```

with that, call the hiding method.

Comment: After some testing, this seems to be the most reliable method.

Comment: Can you send code example? where should i put Toolkit.getEditText(((ViewParent)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)); ?

Comment: Marry me!! I was searching for a good solution for so long. Seems I found a nice (and short) one. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I think if you handle the null case of getCurrentFocus(), you're good to go. I use the method below and it works like a charm!

```
     /* Hide Keyboard */
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View focus = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if(focus != null)
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focus.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

Comment: When using the viewflipper, the View focus is null and thus the keyboard is not hidden. Probably a problem with the viewFlipper?
edit: probably not, rotating screen doesn't hide keyboard either

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct activity and calling the method in the correct place? I think View focus shouldn't be null, if the keyboard is open.

Answer (score 4):

This one works for me always:

```
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(MyActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

kotlin.  Put this on common BaseActivity. just call hideKeyboard() method anywhere in your activity similar apply for Fragment.

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution worked for me:

```
mActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

I had a dialog with input field, hiding the dialog didnt hide the keyboard on tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```